can not get video source url from public videos on facebook graph api
graph.faceboo.com/v20/1075751080778492?fields=source,title
while try the above request to graph api it only giving the following result
{
"title": "5 Moments You Wouldn't Believe if Not Filmed",
"id": "1075751080778492"
}
even after I have gave permission and used both user access token and page access token.
I need the source to my express.js app where I can download the video.
How can I get that?
tried several articles among those one was promising but it answered 10 years ago and I want to know still facebook allowing to access public videos source url because it's not working now but still listed on the apis list.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#permissions: "The source field will not be returned for Page-owned videos unless the User making the request is an admin of the owning Page."

So it can be say which videos I will need I also have to be an admin first of those page!
